# start mediaplayer inside class extending PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

i need to start MP inside class extending `PhoneStateListener`. i have my mp3 file inside assets. any solution as getAssets() is not working inside.

Comment: @Tofeeq- i don't know what just happened all comments were deleted..you got my question..?? it's like just suggest me something so that i can play a file of my choice on incoming call other than the ringtone(Already set)